# Is it possible to "relax" a problem in VS Code?

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, c11

I use VS code on a 64 bit Linux system to develop embedded C applications for a 32bit ARM uC. All of my code will get cross-compiled on a VM by another toolchain that VS Code doesn't know about. Some of my code will be built natively for unit tests. VS Code is using gcc 7.3.0 as its compiler

I have a static_assertion is getting a red squiggle under in VS code because I have asserted that the `offsetof` a struct member is what I expect it to be. This static assert does not fire when I build the code with my target toolchain, and furthermore this isn't a file I intend to unit test. Is there some way to suppress this problem in VS code without totally disabling IntelliSense?

I am using VS Code version 1.33.1.

Edit:
I could define away static asserts based on the configuration. But some static asserts are valuable both cases.

Another option would be to wrap static asserts in a macro that takes a parameter to hide it for one configuration or another. I'd like to avoid decorating my code with things like this to help out one particular editor. My team uses a variety of editors so that wouldn't be acceptable.

I was hoping there would be a way to redefine a macro for a particular file in a workspace perhaps, or suppress a particular compiler error code for a particular file.

Comment: I don't think VS Code has a "suppress red squiggle" option. Is this a gcc compiler error, a VS Code Intellisense warning/error, what?

Comment: Put it in a macro and shove it somewhere you can't see it. Out of sight, out of mind!

Comment: @MarkBenningfield This would be a legitimate GCC compiler error.

Comment: Is including the asserts in a `#ifdef __arm__`/`#endif` couple not a viable option?

Comment: @Bob__ not really. I just edited my question.

Comment: " I'd like to avoid decorating my code with things like this to help out one particular editor." This sort of thing is all-too-often required when using a MS tool chain to build portable C code.

Comment: It would appear that your tool is entirely unsuitable for writing portable programs.